# Porting CRC16 Code in C to C# .NET

Tags: c#, c, port, porting, crc

So I have this C code that I need to port to C#:

C Code:

```
uint16 crc16_calc(volatile uint8* bytes, uint32 length)
{
   uint32 i; 
   uint32 j;
   uint16 crc = 0xFFFF; 
   uint16 word;

   for (i=0; i < length/2 ; i++)
   {
      word = ((uint16*)bytes)[i];

      // upper byte
      j = (uint8)((word ^ crc) >> 8);
      crc = (crc << 8) ^ crc16_table[j];

      // lower byte
      j = (uint8)((word ^ (crc >> 8)) & 0x00FF);
      crc = (crc << 8) ^ crc16_table[j];
   }
   return crc;
}
```

Ported C# Code:

```
public ushort CalculateChecksum(byte[] bytes)
{
    uint j = 0;
    ushort crc = 0xFFFF;
    ushort word;

    for (uint i = 0; i < bytes.Length / 2; i++)
    {
        word = bytes[i];

        // Upper byte
        j = (byte)((word ^ crc) >> 8);
        crc = (ushort)((crc << 8) ^ crc16_table[j]);

        // Lower byte
        j = (byte)((word ^ (crc >> 8)) & 0x00FF);
        crc = (ushort)((crc << 8) ^ crc16_table[j]);
    }

    return crc;
}
```

This C algorithm calculates the CRC16 of the supplied bytes using a lookup table crc16_table[j]

However the Ported C# code does not produce the same results as the C code, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
word = ((uint16*)bytes)[i];
```

reads two bytes from `bytes` into a `uint16`, whereas

```
word = bytes[i];
```

just reads a single byte.

Assuming you're running on a little endian machine, your C# code could change to

```
word  = bytes[i++];
word += bytes[i] << 8;
```

---

Or, probably better, as suggested by MerickOWA

```
word = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, i++);
```

Note that you could avoid the odd-looking extra increment of `i` by changing your loop:

```
for (uint i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i+=2)
{
    word = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, i);
```

Comment: Or using BitConverter.ToInt16